# Google Earth API for Android

Tags: android, google-earth

I want to ask if Google Earth API is avaialble for developing android application.
If google earth api is not available for android, are there any map api which can be used off network on android?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to open a location you can use the intents for searching on Google Earth. See [How to fly to a location in Google Earth from your android app](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1ddcd50dbb6a764d?fwc=1) for examples

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no offline API on Android or Google Earth API. You can use the regular Android Google Maps package api, eventually in combination with the Google Maps web api, in case you need routing and directions as well.

Until SDK 0.9, Google had a navigation package/api included, but that has been dropped; I guess due to licensing issues. Note that real-time turn-by-turn navigation on Android is not allowed and against the ToS, while route navigation in general can be done, but only in combination with the maps web api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source **AndNav** library for offline mapping.  The API is very similar to the Android Google Maps one.  The code can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/andnav/

Their [wiki](http://wiki.andnav.org/index.php/Main_Page) has a lot of good information and downloads for map tile packs.

Comment: But note that AndNav development is discontinued and the current version only uses OSM (OpenStreetMap) afaik.

Comment: Its been about a year since I used it, but it worked well when I needed an offline mapping solution.  It does look like commits are being made: http://code.google.com/p/andnav/updates/list